Estimation of exponential moment of maximum value of CIR process
For $t \leqslant H$, consider the CIR process,
\begin{align*}
d r_t = \kappa_r(\theta_r -r_t) d t + \sigma_r \sqrt{r_t} d W_t,
\end{align*}
where $\kappa_r, \theta_r$ and $\sigma_r$ are positive constants, $W$ is a Brownian motion. I want to know whether exponential moment of maximum value of CIR process exists or not ?  That is
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_r\left(\sup\limits_{0\leqslant s\leqslant H} e^{r_s}\right) < \infty \ ?
\end{align*}
If the maximum value is not added, we can obtain $\mathbb{E}_r\left(e^{r_t}\right)< \infty,\ t\le H$, when $\kappa_r \ge \sigma_r^2$. However, the exponential estimation of the maximum value of $r$ can not be obtained. The main problem is that the coefficients of SDE satisfied by $e^{r_t}$ no longer satisfy linear growth condition.
